# Android Studio Bug? AntergOS Android SDK can't be installed with Android Studio or AUR

Tags: android, linux, android-studio-2.2

OS : Antergos (Linux)

The problem here is the missing Android SDK, I can not install it from either android-studio-2.2 or AUR.

When I tried to install it from the Android SDK, [it does not allow me to check the Android SDK Platform for download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXZc5.png)

Assuming that Android SDK is already installed I proceed to click next only to be met with this [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmBO7.png) which confirms that an Android SDK is installed. I then tried to start a project which the program in turn throw an error saying that the Android SDK is not installed. I then check the settings and found that the Android SDK Location is not set. I google for the location of default Android SDK location, which is $HOME/Android/sdk, which does not exist on my machine. The only conclusion I can make is that Android SDK is not installed on my machine. I tried to install it from android-studio-2.2's GUI but it does not let me tick it while saying that it is installed. I then tried to install the Android SDK from the AUR, which returns 'package filename is not valid'.

I tried installing android-studio-2.2 from both AUR and the official android site, neither let me download Android SDK.

What might be the problem? Is it Antergos? Could it be that the default install path is different than many other path on the internet?

Comment: goto "/home/brandon/.." and delete ".AndroidStudio2.2" (you need to enable show hidden files) and "Android" folder. This will reset old Android Studio setup and start over everything from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you Prokash Sarkar, this solved my problem, unfortunately I can't seem to post an answer.

Comment: I've posted the same answer! It would be helpful if you can accept it now. @Kuo Chong Yii

Comment: Accepted, thank you @Prokash Sarkar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the older **SDK** and **Android Studio** configuration by going to the:

`/home/brandon/..` directory

and deleting **.AndroidStudio2.2** and **Android** folder. Make sure you have enabled hidden directory visibility. This will reset old **Android Studio** setup and start over everything from the beginning.